# SetState does not work to update the data in a widget

Tags: flutter, setstate, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have a DashboardScreen which is accessed from bottom navbar , and another screen called CollectionScreen also is accessed from bottom navbar, when i create a collection on collection screen i need to update the dashboard screen to have that collection, as well as if i download a video in a collection i need to update the dashboard to have the latest video downloaded, the problem when i have a new collection and a video in it, and navigate to dashboard screen through bottom navbar, there is no update of new collection and video in dashboard until i hit hot reload, also the back button on appbar in collection screen does not allow the pop context. anybody to help on this.

i have tried to use setstate to update the widget but nothing work, also i have used future build but the collections are updated but no video is updated.

BottomNavigation page file (LandingPage):

```
import 'package:demo/components/setting.dart';
import 'package:demo/screens/collectionScreen.dart';
import 'package:demo/screens/dashboardScreen.dart';
import 'package:icony/icony_ikonate.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<BottomNavigationBarItem> bottomNavItems = const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Ikonate(
        Ikonate.home_alt2,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      label: "Home",
      backgroundColor: Colors.black),
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Ikonate(
        Ikonate.grid,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      label: "Collections",
      backgroundColor: Colors.black),
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.add_box), label: "", backgroundColor: Colors.black),
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Ikonate(
        Ikonate.settings,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      label: "Settings",
      backgroundColor: Colors.black),
];


class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LandingPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LandingPage> createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _pageController;
  var _selectedPageIndex;

  List<Widget> _screenOptions = <Widget>[
    DashboardScreen(),
    CollectionsScreen(),
    Setting(),
    Setting()
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _selectedPageIndex = 0;
    _screenOptions;
    _pageController  = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _pageController,
        children:_screenOptions,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: bottomNavItems,
        currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        iconSize: 40,
        onTap: (selectedPageIndex) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedPageIndex = selectedPageIndex;
            _pageController.index=selectedPageIndex;
          });
        },
        elevation: 5,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my Dashboard Screen

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:demo/components/ravVideoPlay.dart';
import 'package:demo/model/storage.dart';
import 'package:demo/model/video.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_thumbnail/video_thumbnail.dart';

class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<DashboardScreen> createState() => _DashboardScreenState();
}

class _DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  
  List<String> collections = [];
  List<Video> _videos = [];
  List<Uint8List> collectionThumbnails = [];
  late Video lastVideo = Video(videoUrl: "", music_url: "", filepath: "", thumbnailpath: "", collection: "");

  

  Future<void> _getLatestColl() async {
    try {
      List<String> latestCollections =
          await DatabaseHelper.getLatestCollections();
      List<Video> videos = await DatabaseHelper.getAllVideos();
      List<Uint8List> thumbnails =
          await generateThumbnailsForCollections(latestCollections);

      // Find the latest video
      Video latestVideo = videos.isNotEmpty
          ? videos.last
          : Video(
              videoUrl: "",
              music_url: "",
              filepath: "",
              thumbnailpath: "",
              collection: "");
      collections = latestCollections;
      _videos = videos;
      lastVideo = latestVideo;
      collectionThumbnails = thumbnails;
     
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error loading latest collection and videos: $e");
      // Handle error here
    }
  }

 


  Future<List<Uint8List>> generateThumbnailsForCollections(
      List<String> collections) async {
    final List<Uint8List> thumbnails = [];

    for (final collectionName in collections) {
      final videosInCollection =
          await DatabaseHelper.getVideosInCollection(collectionName);

      // Generate a thumbnail for the first video in the collection (customize as needed)
      if (videosInCollection.isNotEmpty) {
        final videoPath =
            videosInCollection[0].filepath; // Adjust this to get the video path
        final thumbnailData = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
          video: videoPath,
          imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
          quality: 30,
        );
        thumbnails.add(thumbnailData!);
      } else {
        // Add a placeholder thumbnail if no videos are in the collection
        thumbnails
            .add(Uint8List(0)); // Replace with a default placeholder image path
      }
    }

    return thumbnails;
  }


  Widget TitleLabel(var text) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          RichText(
              text: TextSpan(children: [
            TextSpan(
                text: "View All",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white)),
            WidgetSpan(
                child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 16,
              ),
            ))
          ]))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState(); 
    _getLatestColl();
  }

  



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    
    double expandHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.33;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text('Home'),
                  leading: BackButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _getLatestColl(), 
        builder: (context,snapshot){
          if( snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ){
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          }else {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          }else{
            return NestedScrollView(
                    headerSliverBuilder:
                        (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
                      return [
                        SliverAppBar(
                          expandedHeight: expandHeight,
                          floating: true,
                          forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                          pinned: true,
                          titleSpacing: 0,
                          backgroundColor: Color(0x232728),
                          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                            background: Container(
                              height: expandHeight,
                              child: Stack(
                                children: [
                                  if (lastVideo.thumbnailpath.isNotEmpty)
                                  Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                                      child: PageView(
                                        children: [
                                          RecentVideo(
                                            img: lastVideo.thumbnailpath,
                                            callback: () {
                                              Navigator.push(
                                                context,
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                  builder: (_) => VideoPlay(
                                                      videoPath:
                                                          lastVideo.filepath),
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            },
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                  else
                                  Center(child: Text('No Latest Video')),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ];
                    },
                    body: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          TitleLabel("New Collections"),
                          if (collections.isEmpty)
                            Center(child: Text('No Collections'))
                          else  
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 220,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemCount: collections.length,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return RecentCollection(
                                      video: collections[index],
                                      thumbnail: collectionThumbnails[index]);
                                }),
                          ),
                          TitleLabel("Recently Edited"),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 220,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemCount: _videos.length,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return RecentEdited(
                                    video: _videos[index],
                                  );
                                }),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ));
                
            
          }
          }
          
          
        }
        
        ),
    );
  }

}

class RecentVideo extends StatelessWidget {
  final String img;
  final Function callback;
  const RecentVideo({super.key,required this.img, required this.callback});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap:() {
              callback();
            },
            child: Stack(
            
              fit: StackFit.expand,
            
              children: [
                Image.memory(File(img).readAsBytesSync(),fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                Center(
                  child: Icon(Icons.play_circle_fill, size:30)
                ),
              ],
              
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class RecentCollection extends StatelessWidget {
  late String video;
  late Uint8List thumbnail;

  RecentCollection({
    super.key,
    required this.video,
    required this.thumbnail,
    
  });

  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:16),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            child: Image.memory(
              thumbnail, // Use the thumbnail data here
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: 160,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            ),
            
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 4,),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4, right: 4),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(video, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class RecentEdited extends StatelessWidget {
  late Video video;

  RecentEdited({
    super.key,
    required this.video,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            child: Image.asset(
              video.thumbnailpath,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: 160,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 4,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4, right: 4),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  video.collection,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```